# Create an indexed JSON with correct formatting

Tags: javascript, php, json, getjson

I need to create a JSON array in PHP which looks like the following.
The array needs to be created with a PHP While loop.

```
[{
    "latitude":"124",
    "longitude":"",
    "altitude":"87654",
    "title":"test3",
    "description":"This is a test 3",
    "urlidle":"0",
    "urlselected":"0"
}, {
    "latitude":"1ert",
    "longitude":"67",
    "altitude":"9",
    "title":"tes3456",
    "description":"This is a test 123",
    "urlidle":"www.demo.blah",
    "urlselected":"0demo.blah"
}]
```

The PHP loop I implemented is like the follows.

```
$poi=array();
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $poi[$x]['latitude'] = $row['lat'];
    $poi[$x]['longitude'] = $row['long'];
    $poi[$x]['type'] = $row['type'];
    $poi[$x]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $poi[$x]['description'] = $row['desc'];
    $poi[$x]['urlidel'] = $row['url1'];
    $poi[$x]['urlselected'] = $row['url2'];
    $x++;
}
```

And Which can be read by the JS  for loop with method

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(serverUrl, function(data) {

    loadPoisFromJsonData(data);

}
```

But it doesnt seem to be working

Where the ServerUrl is a PHP file that echoes the JSON.

I need the JSON to be read as the follows.

```
function loadPoisFromJsonDataFn(poiData) {

    for (var i = 0; i < poiData.length; i++) {
        var singlePoi = {
            "id": poiData[i].id,
            "latitude": parseFloat(poiData[i].latitude),
            "longitude": parseFloat(poiData[i].longitude),
            "altitude": parseFloat(poiData[i].altitude),
            "title": poiData[currentPlaceNr].name,
            "description": poiData[i].description,
            "urlidle": poiData[i].urlidle,
            "urlselected": poiData[i].urlselected
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) after the data has been added to the array

```
$poi=array();
$x = 0;
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $poi[$x]['latitude'] = $row['lat'];
    $poi[$x]['longitude'] = $row['long'];
    $poi[$x]['type'] = $row['type'];
    $poi[$x]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $poi[$x]['description'] = $row['desc'];
    $poi[$x]['urlidel'] = $row['url1'];
    $poi[$x]['urlselected'] = $row['url2'];
    $x++;
}
print_r($poi);
echo json_encode($poi);
```

You don't need to loop it again in JS. The result(poiData) is already a **JSON**

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(serverUrl, function(data) {

  console.log(data);
  //See it in Firebug, it's already a JSON.

  alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
  //If you want to see it as string

}
```

Comment: I have already used json_encode().
My question is that whether it would be accessible by means of indexes like poiData[i].id inside the JS

Answer (score 0):

```
$poi=array();
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$poi1 = array();
    $poi1['latitude'] = $row['lat'];
    $poi1['longitude'] = $row['long'];
    $poi1['type'] = $row['type'];
    $poi1['title'] = $row['title'];
    $poi1['description'] = $row['desc'];
    $poi1['urlidel'] = $row['url1'];
    $poi1['urlselected'] = $row['url2'];
    $x++;
$poi = $poi1



}

echo json_encode($poi);

    enter code here
```